# Why are the results of the dd command not reflected immediately?

Tags: linux, dd

hi i currently have a question about the result after using dd command.

```
[root@localhost sdb2]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 898M     0  898M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    910M     0  910M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    910M  9.6M  901M   2% /run
tmpfs                    910M     0  910M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   17G  1.3G   16G   8% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  151M  864M  15% /boot
tmpfs                    182M     0  182M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb1                4.8G   20M  4.6G   1% /root/sdb1
/dev/sdb2                4.8G   20M  4.6G   1% /root/sdb2
```

As you can see I split the /dev/sdb disk into 2 partitions and mounted them on /root/sdb1 and /root/sdb2 respectively.

I entered /root/sdb1 and typed `echo hello, world > test.txt` and cloned the partition using `dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdb2`.

Then I went into /root/sdb2 to see if the test.txt file exists, but I couldn't find it.

Why are you doing this? is there something i'm missing?

I don't know why I don't see the contents of test.txt straight away. let me know!

Comment: You are overwriting a mounted partition.

Comment: You should not use a partition/filesystem that is mounted as either the input/source nor as the output/destination of a `dd` command.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Writing to `/root/sdb1/test.txt` modifies the filesystem mounted on `/root/sdb1`. The OS may cache this modification and delay writing to the underlying block device `/dev/sdb1`. In effect `test.txt` is present when you read from the filesystem, but its content may or may not be there when you read `/dev/sdb1`.

Your `dd` read a device containing a filesystem mounted for writing. Not only it might miss some data due to caching; it read different parts of the filesystem at different moments and if the filesystem was modified in the meantime then there is no guarantee all the parts form a coherent filesystem.

Check what [panorama fail](https://www.google.com/search?q=panorama+fail&tbm=isch) is. The reality is coherent at any given moment, but by taking partial images at different moments and joining them together you may get an image that is wrong. It can happen to a filesystem as well.

But this is not why you didn't see `test.txt` in `/root/sdb2`.

Your `dd` not only read from a device containing a filesystem mounted for writing; it wrote to a device containing a mounted filesystem. Most likely the OS knew the content of `/root/sdb2` from before, this information was cached. Writing to `/dev/sdb2` destroyed the old filesystem on the device, but since it did not involve writing to `/root/sdb2` on the filesystem level, the OS did not treat this as a change to the mounted filesystem itself and happily showed you the old (cached) content of `/root/sdb2` without reading anything anew from `/dev/sdb2`.

If you keep using `/root/sdb2`, the OS will eventually write to or read from `/dev/sdb2`. And then:

- writes would make sense as modifications of the old filesystem of `sdb2`, but they will not make sense in the context of the copy of `/dev/sdb1` now present in `/dev/sdb2`; so even if we assume that `dd` luckily managed to copy the filesystem of `sdb1` in some coherent state, using `/root/sdb2` will break it anyway;
- reads will give the OS data from the (possibly "panorama-failed") copy of `sdb1`, while it expects data consistent with the filesystem still mounted on `/root/sdb2`; the filesystem driver may discover inconsistencies and re-mount read-only, or you can get some garbage; in general weird things will happen.

This is why you shouldn't copy the content of a block device when its filesystem is mounted for writing; and why you shouldn't write directly to a block device when its filesystem is mounted at all.

The filesystem on `/dev/sdb1` should still be fine, but the current content of `/dev/sdb2` is most likely a mess (even if it resembles a filesystem).

The right way was to `umount /root/sdb1` and `umount /root/sdb2`, then to copy ([not necessarily with `dd`](https://superuser.com/q/1503409/432690)). Finally you could `mount` both devices again*.

---

<sup>* Except when the filesystem is btrfs. Cloning btrfs and trying to mount the original or the copy when the other is also connected may cause data loss. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1284495/432690) and the links there.</sup>

Comment: I'd add that if you look at any of the commands that wrap fdisk etc., they generally (a) warn sternly that they should not be used to manipulate mounted filesystems and (b) announce "Re-reading partition table" on completion.